# Merging two files in bash with a twist in shell linux

Tags: linux, shell

The following question is somehow tricky but seemingly simple , i need to use bash

let us suppose i have 2 text files, the first on is

FirstFile.txt

```
0 1
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 0
```

SecondFile.txt

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
1 0
1 1
1 2 
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 1 
2 2 
2 3
2 4 
2 5
```

I want to be able to create a new Thirdfile.txt that contains that values that are not in file A , meaning if there is a common variable with file A i want it to be removed. knowing that 2 0 and 0 2 are the same ...

Can you help me out ?

Comment: Please format your question. Add in what you expect, and what you currently get (I am hoping you have put in some effort on your own).

Comment: Is `A.txt` really in `SecondFile.txt`?

Comment: Do it with `awk`. Use the contents of the first file as the keys in an array, canonicalizing the pairs so that the lower number is always first. Then read the second file, canonicalize the pair, and test if it's in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`, you can rearrange the columns so that the lower number is always first. When reading the first file, save them as keys in an associative array. When reading the second file, test if they're not found in the array.

```
awk '{if ($1 <= $2) { a = $1; b = $2; } else { a = $2; b = $1 } }
     FNR==NR { arr[a, b] = 1; next; }
     !arr[a, b]' FirstFile.txt SecondFile.txt > ThirdFile.txt
```

Results:

```
0 3
0 4
0 5
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 2 
2 3
2 4 
2 5
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without the array, in a simpler form ?

Comment: Not that I can think of. You need some way to remember the values from the first file to compare them with the second file.

Comment: The `comm` command can compare the contents of two files, and just show the non-matching lines, but it only checks for exact matches.

Comment: shouldn't your result exclude '2 1' ... and '1 2'?

Comment: @jsp You're right. I needed to use `next`, not `getline`, it was skipping every other line in `FirstFile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
paste <(cut -f2 a.txt) <(cut -f1 a.txt) > tmp.txt
cat a.txt b.txt tmp.txt | sort | uniq -u
```

or

```
cat a.txt b.txt <(paste <(cut -f2 a.txt) <(cut -f1 a.txt)) | sort | uniq -u
```

**Result**

```
0   3
0   4
0   5
1   3
1   4
1   5
2   2
2   3
2   4
2   5
```

**Explanation**

`uniq` removes duplicate rows from a text file.

`uniq` requires that its input be sorted.

`uniq -u` prints only the rows that do not have duplicates.

So, `cat a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq -u` will almost get you there: Only rows in b.txt that are not in a.txt will get printed. However it doesn't handle the reversed cases, like '1 2' <-> '2 1'.

Therefore, you need a temp file that holds all the reversed removal keys.  That's what `paste <(cut -f2 a.txt) <(cut -f1 a.txt)` does.

Note that `cut` assumes columns are separated by \t's.  If they are not, you will need to specify a delimiter with, for example, `-d ' '`.

Comment: You need the `-d " "` option to `paste` and `cut` to use space as the separator instead of tab.

Comment: Ah! I was just adding that! Thanks!

Comment: Very clever. You should improve the answer by explaining how it works.

Comment: Please do explain further and are both operate on a.txt ?